# Picture in Picture mode on back press

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I just wanted to know,
is there a way to integrate Picture in Picture mode on Back press event in flutter?
I have looked for the solution in relates to Picture in Picture mode but didn't find anything helpful.
if someone have idea how can we integrate PIP on Back press, please help me.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bit late but it is possible to find a good number of widgets that can be used for Flutter to get PiP easily integrated. Check for example https://fluttergems.dev/picture-in-picture/

You can use in general this site to find useful code and you can join the community to discuss any topics or challenges.